# Particular bump function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to find a function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which, for fixed $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$, is identically 1 for $x\le a$, identically $0$ for $x\ge b$ and decreases in $a\le x\le b$. I've tried many times to write $f$ in $a\le x\le b$ using an exponential, but it didn't work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the function
$$\varphi(x) = \cases{0 & if $x\le0$,\\e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & if $x\ge0$}$$
as a building block. You can easily prove that $\varphi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Is it $\displaystyle{\varphi(x)=e^{\frac{(x-b)^2}{(x-a)^2}}}$?

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$f (x)=\begin {cases} e^{-1/x^2} & x>0 \\ 0 & otherwise \end {cases} $$
is smooth, increases to 1 from 0. Subtracting it from 1 gives a function that decreases from 1 to 0. Pick your favorite smooth increasing homeomorphism $h $ from $(a,b) $ to $(0,\infty)$. Then define $g(x)=1-f (h (x))$ on $(a,b) $ and extend from there.